# Python lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyErr_ReplaceException

Tags: python, python-2.7, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to set up an SSL certificate with letsencrypt, but when I run it I get the following:

```
user@box:/opt/letsencrypt$ ./letsencrypt-auto --apache -d example.com
Updating letsencrypt and virtual environment dependencies...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
from pip import main
  File "/home/user/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/home/user/.local/share/letsencrypt/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
import zipfile
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py", line 6, in <module>
import io
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
import _io
ImportError: /home/user/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _PyErr_ReplaceException
```

Python -V returns Python 2.7.11.

I've tried a lot of other threads and not managed to get it to work.

Comment: Did you compile Python yourself? If so, at the end of running `make`, were there any modules listed as not having been compiled due to missing dependencies?

Comment: I did it using deadsnakes PPA (ppa:fkrull/deadsnakes). I've just tried an apt-get install --reinstall of it, and reinstalled python-pip, and still getting the same error.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the standard Ubuntu python package? I'd highly recommend installing that, pointing `lets-encrypt` to it, and seeing if the error continues.

Comment: Let's Encrypt [now] requires Python 2.7.x, and isn't compatible with Python 3.x, which makes life a little awkward. Ubuntu's standard package is 2.6.x, which was causing its own lets-encrypt issues sadly.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on?

Comment: Want to join me in the [Python chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)?

Comment: @jacob21 were you able to get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like `io` module is being loaded with against wrong version of `libpython`.

Here's how it looks on my system, `io` uses that symbol and `libpython` provides it:

```
air:~ dima$ nm  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so | grep -i replaceex
                 U __PyErr_ReplaceException
air:~ dima$ nm /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib | grep -i replaceex
00000000000d03a0 T __PyErr_ReplaceException
```

Comment: This is the right answer. But it's hard for the author to deal with the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get to the real cause of this.

After much work I downgraded OS Python to its latest supported default, and created a virtualenv with a newer version of Python (2.7.11 in my case), and ran it from there.